# Classifier score is higher on test set than on training set. Is this an error?

Tags: classification

I am currently getting used to scikit-learn and I trained a simple logistic regression model on the iris dataset. One interesting thing I noticed was when I looked at the classifier.score, namely:

```
classifier.score(X_test, y_test)          0.97368421052631582
classifier.score(X_train, y_train)        0.9553571428571429
```

I split my dataset in the traditional 75%-25% manner and I was expecting the score on the training data to be higher. Is this not always the case ? If not, why not?

Comment: Why do you expect that? If you do the splitting randomly, small or large differences between the split samples may tip either way.